# Onblur issue on text box autocomplete..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, javascript-remoting

I have a VF page..I have a button open pop up..on click of that button i am opening a pop up using output panel and css...using the code something like this..

LINK http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/

On that pop up i am using autocomplete using VF remoting and a confirm button on that popup..My problem is i am using blur event whenever i type some thing in that autocomplete text box i am selecting a autocomplete record and on onblur event calling a method but the curser remains in that text box.So when i click a confirm button onblur event is again called calling the controller method.

I want the curser to move out of the textbox after onblur event ..?? I need some jquery/javascript code...

```
close: function(){
      j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).blur();
   }
```

Please help i am stuck with this issue...for 3 days...

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm finding it hard to interpret your question. Can you provide more code examples?

I think you're using blur() wrong. Wouldn't you want to use a typing timer? Something that queries for auto-complete answers only after the user has stopped typing? That's the best I can say at this point.